# How to finish a fragment using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I tried things like `activity?.finsish` but it closed the complete app.
This is where I want to finish the frgament:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(2000)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_authenticationFragment)
       // Here I want to finish my Fragment
    }
```

Is there another solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.splashFragment, true).build()
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_authenticationFragment, null, navOptions)
```